# Why is there arguments if everything was passed down from Moshe Rabeinu?

Tags: oral-torah, halacha-lemoshe-misinai

If the oral law is from Moshe Rabeinu, why in the Gemara / Mishnah does it sound like the rabbis are discussing it in a way where they are just deciding it for the first time? They are discussing back and forth what the law should be. Wasn't it passed down from Moshe? Why is there an argument for everything?

Comment: Excellent question. I have exactly the book you need to read: https://www.amazon.com/Dynamics-Dispute-Makings-Machlokess-Talmudic/dp/0910818991